# I can authenticate but can not login in using my password?

Tags: login, password, authentication

Here is my story :

- there were days when I had my password and everything was fine.
- I removed my password :

  - Opened **`User accounts`**
  - Unlocked it by pressing "Unlock" button
  - Selected my username (btw, I have only one user which is Administrator user)
  - Chose "Login without password"
  - Pressed "Change" button
- and some day there came a trouble
- i needed to authenticate (as I had no password I could not authenticate)
- using **`Startup Disk Creator`** wrote Ubuntu 12.04 to a USB.
- I "tried Ubuntu"
- mounted my Ubuntu's `filesystem` (not Try Ubuntu's)
- in terminal run **`gksu nautilus`** (No authentication was necessary)
- opened **`etc/shadow`** file, and removed `some_encrypted_text` from this line :

  - `wicked6:some_encrypted_text:15864:0:99999:7:::`
- Rebooted and opened my Ubuntu

  - in terminal run `passwd myusername` and changed my password
- I got the message **`passwd: password updated successfully`**
- I can use this password for authentication but not for logging in by pressing login button (I can log in directly on first log in {Remember that I had used **`login without password`**}. But when I lock my screen I need to press `switch user` and then press `login`, because when I enter my password it does not accept it)

Please don't advice me to reinstall Ubuntu, because I don't want. Help me to login in on Lock Screen. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 :-)

Comment: Can anyone tell me when I will get answer so that I won't need keep pressing F5 all the time :)

Comment: Viewed 16 times and not a single answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you chosen  "Login without password" this is useful only to pass by the login screen without password. This doesn't mean that you don't still have a password. You will still need your password sometimes (for example when you use a command with `sudo` or `gksu`).

I can advise you to change again your password to the old one from terminal with `passwd` command and search for `/etc/shadow~` (with`~` at the end) file or `/etc/shadow-` (with`-` at the end) file (this is a backup for `/etc/shadow` file). If you find it, rename it with the original one (`sudo mv /etc/shadow~ /etc/shadow`).

Comment: **If I had changed my password several times before which password it will recover to ?** Actually I found my password by trying every of my previous passwords, but I'm curious. And thanks for your patience while reading my question. :)